# PHP - Get More Server Information VIA Internet Protocol Address

Tags: php, ip

I currently run `pingrglobe.com` and I am looking to find out how I would get information such as server operating system, web server type(if any)...

So far I've found this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

But, it doesn't seem to be what I need.

I've been looking around and can't find the tutorials I need to get information like server type, operating system etc using php and IP.

Comment: Why the -1 already? Reasons? If more information is needed for the +1, ask me please. :)

Comment: Probably the -1 because you don't seem to have done much research

Comment: In many cases you won't be able to get much information, unless the machine is running a web server (you can then parse the response from a web page request). Otherwise machines don't generally broadcast that type of information publicly

Comment: @MarkBaker - who.is/whois/ubuntu.org - whois done it! :/

Comment: I'll rewrite what I wrote before with some additional emphasis: __unless the machine is running a web server (you can then parse the response from a web page request).__ but as that information can be changed or suppressed, it can't be relied upon; and if the machine isn't running a web server, what can you check?

Comment: Well, I want to try getting it, if it fails, I echo "N/A";

Comment: So try.... send an http curl request to the server and look at any response that it gives

Comment: I suck at CURL - could you maybe link me to a good example? Thanks a lot for sticking to my question. :)

Comment: Please [review the information on how to format your post](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  You don't need to use HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example of Ubuntu.org

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ubuntu.org");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
ob_start();
$header = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
$result = ob_get_flush();
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($header);
var_dump($info);
var_dump($result);
```

Then take a look at the contents of $result;